# Different results for almost same code in C (pointers)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I was trying to implement merge sort for the first time, that too with only one array. I just typed whatever came in mind at first, which is irrelevant.

The problem is, I get different results by just adding or removing a printf statement.

without printf:

```
int main(void)
{
    merge_sort( &(pairs[0]), pair_count);
        printf("pair_count address: %p\n", &pair_count);
    printf("pairs address: %p\n", &pairs[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %i       %i \n", i, pairs[i]);
    }
}
```

output:

```
pair_count address: 0x60103c
pairs address: 0x601030
i: 0       10 
i: 1       6 
i: 2       6 
i: 3       6 
i: 4       0 
i: 5       0
```

with printf:

```
int main(void)
{
    merge_sort( &(pairs[0]), pair_count);
        printf("pair_count address: %p\n", &pair_count);
    printf("pairs address: %p\n", &pairs[0]);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", pair_count);
        printf("i: %i       %i      address: %p\n", i, pairs[i], &pairs[i]);
    }
}
```

output:

```
pair_count address: 0x60103c
pairs address: 0x601030
3
i: 0       10      address: 0x601030
3
i: 1       6      address: 0x601034
3
i: 2       4      address: 0x601038
```

I know the reason of error in first case, my code is broken and pointers aren't a thing to play with. Basically, my code edits `pair_count` variable through multiple calls and/or exceeds array length. But I don't understand, the different result in case 2.

On some experiments, I found the loops stops after 3 iterations if:

- I add address of each element of `pairs` array.
- There is another printf statement above it.

I can make no sense out of it.

Here's everything above main, I suppose which doesn't matter much.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pairs[3] = {10, 6, 4};
int pair_count = 3;

void merge(int *p_left, int left, int *p_right, int right);

void merge_sort(int *arr_pointer, int length)
{
    if ( length == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int left = length / 2;
    merge_sort(arr_pointer, left);

    int right = length - left;
    merge_sort((arr_pointer + left), right);

    merge(arr_pointer, left, (arr_pointer + left), right);

    return ;
}

void merge(int *p_left, int left, int *p_right, int right)
{
    int k, index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++)
    {
        for (int j = k; j < right; j++)
        {
            if (*(p_left + i) > *(p_right + j))
            {
                k = j + 1;
                *(p_left + index++) = *(p_left + i);
                if (i == left - 1)
                {
                    for ( ; j < right; j++)
                    {
                        *(p_left + index++) = *(p_right + j);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                *(p_left + index++) = *(p_right + j);
                if (j == right - 1)
                {
                    for ( ; i < left; i++)
                    {
                        *(p_left + index++) = *(p_left + i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. You should ask a specific question. You say you know the reason for the error in the first case, and it involves your code being broken and exceeding array length. So, you are stomping on some memory you should not, and that breaks your program. What is your question? Do you want to know why case 2 is different? That would not be a very interesting question; once you are writing to memory you should not, it is well known and expected it can cause diverse effects on the program that may be sensitive to small changes in the source code.

Comment: `it is well known and expected it can cause diverse effects on the program that may be sensitive to small changes in the source code` ... I did not know that. does that differ with compilers?

Comment: No, it does not particularly differ with compilers. If you write memory where you are not supposed to, it can break whatever tries to use that memory. That memory could be used by another of your variables, by some part of the stack frame such as the return address or frame pointer, as a buffer for some library routine, all sorts of things. If you change the program slightly, it may move things around in memory, so what is affected by overrunning a buffer can easily change.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Thanks. Is assembly code the only way to know what exaclty is happening?

Comment: Sometimes things can be deduced by experiment or other means, but assembly is a direct way to investigate. However, this specific issue is likely not worth investigating. I favor understanding how compilers work and learning to recognize various symptoms as clues to causes, but this does not seem like a productive situation for that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why they're different:

- Your code, by accessing past the end of an array, contains [undefined behavior](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213). Modern compilers assume that undefined behavior will *never* happen, so when it does, they'll get confused and might mess up your program.
- C doesn't guarantee where a variable is allocated. So even if the programs were 100% correct, the pointer values may still change, because the compiler decides that one layout or another is better.

Comment: I see the address of all variables, globals are stored "back-to-back". locals are far away. And they don't seem to change after a call to function. Can you elaborate the second point a little more?